# Trying to get the start and end point of each line within a text pane

Tags: jtextpane

Trying to get the start and end point of each line within a text pane:
The text pane contains (note target is the end of each line not including the blank space line):

(blank space line)
MVESMKKVAGMDVELTVEERN000TAQEGDHGSHVYTKQKEENKGGEDKLKMIREYRQMVETELKLICCDILDVLDKHDDDDDKVFYYKMKGDYHRYLAEFATGNDRKEAAENSLVAYKAASDIAMTELPPTHPIRLGLALNFSVFYYEILNSPDRACRLAKAAFDDAIAELDTLSEESYKDS00000VQVGQQRSDMQGDGKKKAAAEEQNKEALQDVEDENQtarget
MVESMKKVAGMDVELTVEERN000TAQEGDHGSHVYTKQKEENKGGEDKLKMIREYRQMVETELKLICCDILDVLDKHDDDDDDVFYYKMKGDYHRYLAEFATGNDRKEAAENSLVAYKAASDIAMTELPPTHPIRLGLALNFSVFYYEILNSPDRACRLAKAAFDDAIAELDTLSEESYKDS00000VQVGQQRSDMQGDGKKKAAAEEQNKEALQDVEDENQtarget
MVESMKKVAGMDVELTVEERN000TAQEGDHGSHVYTKQKEENKGGEDKLKMIREYRQMVETELKLICCDILDVLDKHDDDDDDDFYYKMKGDYHRYLAEFATGNDRKEAAENSLVAYKAASDIAMTELPPTHPIRLGLALNFSVFYYEILNSPDRACRLAKAAFDDAIAELDTLSEESYKDS00000VQVGQQRSDMQGDGKKKDDDDDDDEEQNKEALQDVEDENQtarget

//This is what I have

```
        Element root = jTextPane1.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();

        Element one = root.getElement(0);
        while (one !=null){            
        int one1 = one.getStartOffset();
        int two1 = one.getEndOffset();
        System.out.println(one1);
        System.out.println(two1);
        one = root.getElement(two1);          
     }
```

This is what I get (1st and 2nd element) and then hangs:
0
1
1
232

Answer (score 1):

You mix model and view. `Document` is just model but amount of rows depends on view (width of content).

Use `javax.swing.text.Utilities.getRowStart()/getRowEnd()`

See an example of the code usage http://java-sl.com/tip_row_column.html