# Detecting number of lines in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

My program fills a JTextPane with various messages, some extending the JTextPane to 2 lines to fit the text, and some only one line. I want the pane to always be two lines. Is there a way to return the amount of lines that text in a JTextPane is currently occupying?

Comment: The [javax.swing.text.Utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Utilities.html) class will likely help you fix your problem.

Comment: This question was originally closed as a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002238/trying-to-get-the-start-and-end-point-of-each-line-within-a-text-pane. Not sure how that posting answers the question since there could be a single line of text that wraps onto a second line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to return the amount of lines that text in a JTextPane is currently occupying?

Check out [Text Utilities](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/), which is not the same as the link provided in the comment.

You should be able to use the `getWrappedLines(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

This will give number of line in JTextPane :

First Option:

```
int lineCount = textPane.getText().split("\n").length + 1;
```

Second Option:

```
Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
int lineCount = new JTextArea(doc).getLineCount();
```